# MySQL expiration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Has MySQL some kind of functionality to expire a certain row after **x seconds**?

For example, I have to following database:

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

subscriptions
    id - integer
    name - string

user_subscriptions
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    subscription_id - integer
    created_at - date
    updated_at - date
```

In this case we have a pivot table user_subscriptions and I want to automatically remove a row within user_subscriptions in **x seconds**

Is this possible within MySQL, if so how?

Comment: Create php cron script to delete expired records.

Comment: It is not possible within MySQL? Redis has possibilities for expiration, so I was wondering if MySQL could do the same.

Comment: It would help if your user_subscriptions table had a timestamp in it so you can determine how old a record is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create events that are run to a schedule to tidy up the database

- See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

This will run independent of PHP and CRON.

But be careful not to lock the table

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans [The documentation is full of examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Answer (score 1):

Approximately:

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
DO DELETE FROM user_subscriptions us WHERE timediff(NOW(), us.timestamp) > INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

See Ed Heal's answer for regular jobs.

If you fear that this uses too much resources when run too often, you could also temporarily simulate the desired behavior until the next run by adding a timestamp column (e.g. named subscription_date) to `user_subscriptions` and create a database view which hides the expired subscriptions:

```
-- shows only subscriptions of the last hour
create view user_subscriptions_view as
select id, user_id, subscription_id 
from user_subscriptions
where subscription_date > subtime(now(),'1:0:0')
```